Update the array based on Checkbox status in ReactJs
I want to update the filterCandidates array based on the total experience of the candidate when the selected checkbox is checked and remove the candidate data from the  array when unchecked, below is the code snippet
import { useState } from "react";

function ExperienceFilter({ candidates }) {
  const [filteredCandidates, setFilteredCandidates] = useState([]);
  const experienceOptions = [
    { value: "1-2", label: "1-2 Years" },
    { value: "3-4", label: "3-4 Years" },
    { value: "5-6", label: "5-6 Years" },
    { value: "7-8", label: "7-8 Years" },
    { value: "9-10", label: "9-10 Years" },
  ];

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    const experiencedCandidates = candidates.filter(
      (candidate) => candidate.totalExperience == value
    );

    if (checked) {
      setFilteredCandidates([...filteredCandidates, experiencedCandidates]);
    }

    if (!checked) {
      setFilteredCandidates((prev) => prev.totalExperience != value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="flex flex-col space-y-3 bg-green-600  px-5 pr-20 py-10">
        <div>Years of Experience</div>
        {experienceOptions.map((option, index) => (
          <label key={index}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={option.value}
              name={option.label}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {option.label}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExperienceFilter;


Do you have a specific question? Some specific issue or problem you need help with? Can you [edit] to clarify?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
